# iOS shortcuts: Is there any way to input key presses into a call after it is connected?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

What I'm looking to do is create a shortcut to call into a work conference line that has a fairly complex set of key presses and voice input needed to connect. Here are the steps for manually connecting:

1. Call main number
2. 7
3. Wait (comma pause)
4. 1234#
5. Wait (comma pause)
6. Speak name
7. #

In the contact phone number itself, I have everything through number 5 working with a series of well timed “pauses” (i.e. NNN-NNN-NNNN,,7,,,1234#,,,).  Technically I can make the whole series work this way if I'm content to speak my own name but this is an exercise in curiosity more than necessity.

I can get Siri to speak my name from text (not sure if it will be heard by the phone mic yet).  But I can’t seem to pause that step until the previous steps are complete.  Since I can’t anticipate how long it will take for the call to initially connect, I can’t simply pause that step for a fixed number of seconds.

The other thing I can’t figure out is how to automate the final # keypress (in the shortcuts command chain) after the voice input where the call is already connected.

Any help is appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: I am also interested in this type of automatism. Could you show me the path you followed up to point 5? I am trying but I am not being able to dial numbers during a call. I did not understand how to do and to make you wait "x" seconds I would be able

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I ran this and discovered that unless you turn on the speaker phone, the spoken audio will come through the phone headset.

You could try doing this as a shortcut.

Step 1, you would have to have the phone dial the sequence that you have listed with the pauses.  That would have to be a pre-set contact.

Step 2, you have to set a Wait. You'd have to set the seconds that you need to wait for the call to go through, step through the dial in prompts, before this next step.

Step 3, turn up your volume to 100%

Step 4 would be to speak your name. You enter in your name and you can choose the voice you want to speak it. (see top.)

Good luck!